# how to clone an azure dev ops git repo using PAT with command line git or sourcetree?

Tags: git, azure

ok, our org has the code in an azure dev ops repo.

I have been trying to clone it via git command line on the mac, via sourcetree on the mac and via sourcetree on windows, with no luck.

I created a PAT in the azure git web UI.

on the mac, if I do:

```
$ git clone https://ourorg.visualstudio.com/CMS/_git/ourProj
Cloning into 'ourProj'...
Username for 'https://ourorg.visualstudio.com': xxx
Password for 'https://xxx@ourorg.visualstudio.com': 
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://ourorg.visualstudio.com/CMS/_git/ourProj/'
```

For user, I tried my azure user, and I also tried the PAT.
For pass, I tired my azure pass, and also the PAT.

None of these options work.

For sourcetree, I have also tried these combinations o PAT/PAT user/PAT user/pass etc. with no luck.  Any suggestions?

This is the page I used to create the PAT:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops

This doc says to use the PAT as the user and pass, but this simply doesnt work.

the doc also says you can do this:

```
git clone https://anything:{yourPAT}@dev.azure.com/yourOrgName/yourProjectName/_git/yourRepoName
```

But this does not work either.

e.g. If I do this (fixed thanks to jessejouwing):

```
$ git clone https://asdf:{myPATgoesHERE}@dev.azure.com/ourorg/CMS/_git/ourProj
```

On windows I always get:

Cloning into 'ourProj'...
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://dev.azure.com/ourorg/CMS/_git/ourProj/'

The PAT is 100% correct.

Unfortunately, "alternative credentials" is disabled in our org, so we have to use PAT.  PAT is not working, so I cant work.

Comment: Try: `.` as user and your PAT as password.

Comment: thanks jessehouwing, but "." didnt work unfortunately.

Comment: `https://asdf:{myPATgoesHERE}@dev.azure.com/ourorg.visualstudio.com/CMS/_git/ourProj` shouldn't contain `.visualstudio.com`.

Comment: https://<PAT>@username.visualstudio.com/myrepos/_git/myproject

Answer (score 3):

```
git clone https://{yourPAT}@dev.azure.com/yourOrgName/yourProjectName/_git/yourRepoName
```

That should suffice.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesnt work.  PAT seems to be disabled or similar. The only thing which works is to clone in visual studio when logged into our azure portal. All other access methods always fail, so no other tools nor command line options are possible. This is driving us crazy.

Comment: "PAT seems to be disabled or similar" - You have to create a new PAT by clicking on "user settings" on top right of the page. (in case you haven't tried that already)

Comment: "Alternate Credentials" is different, that's disabled for my org too. But PAT could be available.

Answer (score 1):

Just click on Generate Git Credentials and use it to authenticate / clone your repo:

[image]

Comment: Generating git credentials, rather than using a PAT seems to work for command line git on mac, but unfortunately won't work for sourcetree, which only supports PAT with azure dev ops selected as hosting source.

Comment: Unfortunately, our org has disabled "alternative credentials", so I cant find any way to checkout code using the PAT

Comment: I use Azure DevOps 2019 and i dont see any "Generate Git credentials"

Answer (score 0):

if you want to avoid personalAccessTokens and have the Azure CLI installed, you can use following snippet

```
az login --allow-no-subscriptions --tenant $tenant 
$azureDevOpsToken = az account get-access-token --resource '499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798' --query accessToken --output tsv --tenant $tenant
git clone "https://$azureDevOpsToken@dev.azure.com/$organization/$projectName/_git/$repositoyName"
```